# How to test WebHooks without an on-premise external system?

Tags: json, rest, post, integration, webhooks

I'm trying to teach myself about integrating systems via WebHooks.

---

In a [free/hosted](https://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html) GIS system, I can [create a WebHook](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370574/invoke-an-http-request-when-agol-features-are-edited) that would, in theory, [POST a JSON object](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/web-hooks-create-feature-service-.htm) to an external system.

The problem is, I don't have an external system that's available right now for for **receiving the POST**.

I think I need some sort of publicly available sample server that would:

- Receive the POST requests
- Do *something* with the requests (ie. create some sort of record)

...so that I could determine if the WebHook worked correctly or not.

---

How can I test my WebHooks without having an on-premise external system?

- *I've poked around websites like Postman Echo and Amazon Lambda. But to my untrained eye, it seems like they're not quite designed for what I need.*

Comment: *It's occurred to me that I've most likely misunderstood some of the concepts I mentioned in this post. Please feel free correct me.*

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of these options depending on your requirements:

1. You could use webhooks modules in services like [Integromat](https://www.integromat.com/?pc=buchu18) or [Zapier](https://zapier.com) to receive webhook data and then apply transformation.
2. You could deploy a script on heroku and use the URL generated there to send the webhooks calls.
3. You could also use services like [requestbin](https://requestbin.com), [webhook.site](http://webhook.site) etc if you just want to receive webhooks data.
   Regards